# Flex maps howto examples

Tags: apache-flex, dictionary

I've stumbled upon this flash map

http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/special/nation/unemployment-by-county/

it looks like they used this map to construct the website.

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:USA_Counties_with_FIPS_and_names.svg

I am curious as to what people have done or any blogs that describe what can be done with flex and simple maps like this (not google maps style maps) but simple all-in-memory maps like this one.  It would be cool to see what/ and how flex can do in terms of maps.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to draw the entire map. Its more of like a custom component. The below class would is how to start with.

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html